# Want some animation in custom UITableView edit mode

Tags: iphone

I have very custom TableView like Add Contact View in iPhone's Contacts.
I like the way this view arrange rows in animation when I click Edit button.

My table view has for example 2 rows of editable information and 6 rows non-editable.
I wrote some code and this 6 non-editable rows disappear from screen when user click my custom Edit button. But its very "flat" and not interesting. Its just remove rows and reloadData then;

**I want to add some nice animation in process of removing cell and appearing back after "Done" click.**

I can't use standard "setEditing animated" because my view custom and I don't need insert or delete rows - i just edit information in it;

Thanks :)

Comment: oh i think i found it in documantation )

    [tv beginUpdates];
    [tv insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    [tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [tv endUpdates];

Comment: @sergnsk Yes, this is the way to go. If you found the answer for your question yourself, please consider to post it as an answer and accept it. This would make your question more useful for others.

Comment: oh thx, i can accept my own answers only in 2 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh i think i found it in documantation )

```
[tv beginUpdates]; 
[tv insertRowsAtIndexPaths:insertIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight]; 
[tv deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:deleteIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade]; 
[tv endUpdates];
```